# How to sum all the values of specific keys belonging to sub-dictionaries

Tags: python

Let’s say I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
main_list = [
    {"Afghanistan":{"1990":23000, "1991":29000, "1992":40000}},
    {"Armenia": {"1990":40000, "1991":32211, "1992":89999}}
]
```

I want to sum all the values of the. keys of the sub dictionaries: so by the end I wanna get something like this: 23000 + 40000 (for year 1990), 29000 + 32211 (for year 1991) etc.
I already know how to do it by looping and checking for conditions in a very conventional way.However what could be the cleanest way of performing this operation?I have seen that there are some external libraries that can help you do something like this without too much pain.This is a very trivial example there are certain cases where the problem can get quite messy, so if there was something to group the data fast would be nice.I do not wanna use pandas.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a complex dictionary comprehension but I think this is clearer:

```
from collections import defaultdict

D = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
main_list = [
    {"Afghanistan":{"1990":23000, "1991":29000, "1992":40000}},
    {"Armenia": {"1990":40000, "1991":32211, "1992":89999}}
]
for d in main_list:
    for k in d.keys():
        for _k, _v in d[k].items():
            D[_k] += _v
print(dict(D))
```

Comment: I think `D = defaultdict(lambda: 0)` is the same as `D = defaultdict(int)`

Comment: It's effectively the same but I tend to use lambda always for defaultdict as my defaults are often far more complex. It's just a personal style thing

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your data once and sort the values by year in a dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

main_list = [
    {"Afghanistan":{"1990":23000, "1991":29000, "1992":40000}},
    {"Armenia": {"1990":40000, "1991":32211, "1992":89999}}
]

d = defaultdict(int)
for country in main_list:
    for data in country.values():
        for year, value in data.items():
            d[year] += value
```

If possible and convenient, I would suggest making `main_list` a dictionary instead as it seems to make more sense.

```
main_list = {
    "Afghanistan":{"1990":23000, "1991":29000, "1992":40000},
    "Armenia": {"1990":40000, "1991":32211, "1992":89999},
}
```

Then for looping you can skip over the `for country in main_list` layer.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, that is, if you want to add values of same indexes, then this should work

```py
main_list = [
    {"Afghanistan":{"1990":23000, "1991":29000, "1992":40000}},
    {"Armenia": {"1990":40000, "1991":32211, "1992":89999}}
]
keys = list(main_list[0].values())[0].keys() #all the keys WARNING: THIS WILL ONLY WORK IF THE KEYS ARE SAME
vals = [list(i.values())[0].values() for i in main_list] #get the all the values
combined = list(zip(*vals)) #merge them in a way that the indexes are same, such as 23,000 to 40,000
print(dict(zip(keys, list(map(sum, combined))))) #add all and display the result
```

Comment: this answer is overly complex

Comment: maybe if it wasn't list it would be muchhhhhhh moreeeee easier like 10000000x because in this case you have to first get the item of list, then the dict, then another dict inside it that's why but after like vals variable its not that complex, just combining them in the order you require and printing them

Comment: well man compare your answer to everyone else’s

Comment: you know they're kinda the same but i have just made it to be more compact